# Standard datatypes of Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I read somewhere, but i got confused. They asked, Datatypes of informatica. Informatica is tool, not a programming language. So, How informatica has own datatypes. Still if it is available then please let me know.

Also tell me, what are the informatica datatypes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *datatype* is not a concept exclusive to programming languages. Excel is a tool and yet you can set a cell's datatype (called *category* in Excel) to `Number`, `Date`, `Percentage` and a few others.

Different transformations support different datatypes, but here's a list for an expression:

- `bigint`
- `binary`
- `date/time`
- `decimal`
- `double`
- `integer`
- `nstring`
- `ntext`
- `real`
- `small integer`
- `string`
- `text`

Comment: @ Marek-Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica has its own set of datatypes, because it is useful to converting any source datatypes (database/files)into `Informatica compatible datatypes for further processing.`

Whenever you drag any source definition in a mapping it automatically creates a source qualifier which converts source datatypes into suitable Informatica datatypes.

Answer (score -1):

*In informatica various data types are supported ( depending on transformation and clients requirements) .
Below are the most usable data types :*

1. bigint
2. small integer
3. date/time
4. date
5. decimal
6. double
7. integer
8. nstring
9. string